# AWS Glacier total storage size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

How can we get the total amount of data that is storage in Glacier storage on AWS ?

Used S3 lifecylce to move data from S3 to Glacier.

Comment: Could you please clarify... what is your question? Are you trying to find the size of the data that you have stored in Glacier via an S3 lifecycle policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can now check total size of AWS Glacier from Cost Explorer by selecting Usage Type Group to S3 Storage:Glacier as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the total amount of data you have in Amazon Glacier that was transferred via Amazon S3 lifecycle policies, some options are:

- You could look at your bill, or
- Use [Amazon S3 Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to dump a file of all your objects and then add up the storage for all objects in the Glacier storage class,
- Write a script that lists S3 objects and adds up the total for objects in the Glacier storage class

Comment: On Cloudwatch I could see the total storage of my S3 bucket.
Are there any similar way to see for Glacier ?
I have millions of objects so guess there would be get charges for S3 Inventory.

Comment: When you lifecycle data from S3 to Glacier, I don't think the data actually shows as being in Glacier. It's treated as being in S3, with a Storage Class of Glacier and the Glacier vault is managed by AWS rather than being visible in your own account. Thus, it won't show any statistics for Glacier usage unless you actually store data in Glacier itself (I believe).